# Angular ng-class: how to use Fuction and conditional expression together?

Tags: angularjs

how to combine such usage of ng-class?
I need to use together function hich returns class, and expression, which evaluates another class

`data-ng-class="{active: field.Selected} getDisplayClass(field.Size)"`

Comment: Does this not work? Does it throw an error? Also - shouldn't the attribute be simply `ng-class`, not `data-ng-class`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows

```
<div data-ng-class="{active: field.Selected}" class="{{ getDisplayClass(field.Size) }}"> ... </div>
```